# Binding textblock foreground color not working

Tags: c#, xaml

xaml code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ChkTemplate"
                         TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                    
                <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0">
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <Binding Path="IsSelected"
                                 Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                <RelativeSource Mode="TemplatedParent" />
                            </Binding.RelativeSource>
                        </Binding>                                
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>                    
                <ContentPresenter />                    
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>                    
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ABC:Info}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
          Margin="0,0,10,5" Foreground="Green"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel}"
           Margin="3,0,0,0"
           Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible,ElementName=View, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}" />
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Foreground}" />
        </TextBlock.Foreground>                   
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>   
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem"
               x:Key="SelectedItem">
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource ChkTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

class:

```
public class Info : DependencyObject
    {      
           public Brush Foreground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

xaml.cs:

```
private readonly RangeObservableCollection<Info> _validInfo;

Info.Foreground = Brushes.Red;                                        
_validInfo.Add(Info);
```

Above code is not changing foreground color of textblock what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Dont you need a SolidColorBrush? I dont think a brush has a Color Property.

Comment: What is the DataContext of second the TextBlock? Does this object really have a property called Foreground? You can check that easily with [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). You should also check the debug output for any warnings, failed bindings usually are printed in the output.

Comment: @ColinPear - You think using SolidColorBrush will work? I am not getting any errors though?

Comment: @dowhilefor - Not getting any compile errors or warnings.

Comment: @ColinPear - Tried using SolidColorBrush did not make any difference color is still green.

Comment: It looks like the ForegroundColor is hard coded to green. Take a look at this and see if it provides [some insight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353730/wpf-how-to-change-the-foreground-color-of-a-textbox-depending-on-the-text-prope).

Comment: @ColinPear - If i remove the hard coded green value. The text does not show at all.

Answer (score 1):

i tried your code and in works for me. can you post the code where your datatemplate comes into action? i do it with a listbox.

EDIT

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Info> _source;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.MySource = new ObservableCollection<Info>();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;


        this.MySource.Add(new Info(){Foreground = Brushes.Red});
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Info> MySource
    {
        get { return _source; }
        set { _source = value; }
    }
}

public class Info : DependencyObject
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Foreground", typeof(Brush), typeof(Info));

    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TestForeground:Info}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @blindmeis - Sorry for late reply. Its binded to checkbox. I updated my code. But it is still not working.

Comment: a checkbox i no content presenter - so the datatemplate with your foreground binding will never happen? or do i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

First off, for any future questions, I'd be sure to provide a "complete" example - the code you've pasted in requires a bit of tinkering to even get running.

That said, there are a number of typos in there that could be causing problems - the following slightly cleaned up code binds properly:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanConverter"/>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ChkTemplate"
                         TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0" 
                                IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"/>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication1:Info}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                Margin="0,0,10,5" 
                                Foreground="Green"/>
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Channel}" 
                    Margin="3,0,0,0" 
                    Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"
                    Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ChkTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Infos}">
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<Info> _validInfo;

        public Window1()
        {
            _validInfo = new ObservableCollection<Info>();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            var info = new Info();
            info.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            info.Visible = true;
            info.Channel = "not sure";
            _validInfo.Add(info);
            info = new Info();
            info.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
            info.Visible = true;
            info.Channel = "also not sure";
            _validInfo.Add(info);

        }

        public ObservableCollection<Info> Infos { get { return _validInfo; } }
    }

    public class Info : DependencyObject
    {
        public Brush Foreground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool Visible { get; set; }
        public string Channel { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", Channel, Foreground, Visible);
        }
    }
}
```